# Help with a constant-voltage LED driver

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current

I have a 33 V, 0.8 A constant voltage LED driver (see picture below, the item no. is GL-1201C-8 if that helps) which no longer works. I searched online but can't find it for an acceptable price.

[image]

I understand the difference between a constant-current driver and a constant-voltage driver but I can't find out if I can use a driver with slightly different specs like [this one](https://www.reichelt.de/led-power-supply-36-w-36-v-dc-1-a-ip67-glp-gpv-35-36-p247115.html?trstct=pol_10&nbc=1&&r=1)
(summary: output 36 W, 36 V DC, 1 A)

Can you help me on that?

Can I use a constant current driver instead of a constant voltage driver? I think I can't in this case, is that correct?

Comment: Q2: Depends. Is the operating current of the constant voltage load within the adjustable range of your CC supply? If you are uncertain - don’t.

Comment: What are the specifications of the LEDs?

Comment: It depends on how your LEDs are wired. If constant current of 0.8A was used, then you need another CC 0.8A, not a CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A replacement constant current driver should be both of the following:

1. Rated for the same **or lower current**
2. Rated for the same **or larger voltage range**

In this case the voltage range of the new constant current driver would need to extend to at least 33V and significantly lower (no lower limit is given on the old driver) and it should be no more than 0.8 A (with lower drive currents making the light dimmer).

The linked replacement is not a constant current LED driver, so it will not work.